# vb.net startup form versus module Main()

Tags: vb.net

Visual basic.net startup form is enabled by default when enable application framework is checked.  With this you can code the application events like reflection and you cannot use module Main().

I have a code below in my application, the same as from `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYgJMRLTc1A`

```
private withevents domain as appdomain = appdomain.currentdomain
private function domaincheck( etc ... )
   if e.name.contains('name0') then
      return system.reflection.assembly.load(my.resources.resname0)
   elseif e.name.contains('name1') then
      return system.reflection.assembly.load(my.resources.resname1)
   elseif e.name.contains('name2') then
      return system.reflection.assembly.load(my.resources.resname2)
   else
      return nothing
   end if
end function
```

I wanted to extract a resource before executing the codes in the function domaincheck.

I tried to place my resource extraction in the first line of code inside the domaincheck function but it somehow loops for many times.  therefore, the resource extraction is extracted many times as the loop.

Where do I place my resource extract code so that it will not loop?

And can I still use the module Main() as my startup form ?  if yes, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

There is ALWAYS a `Main` method. You just can't see it if you have the Application Framework enabled. It's not a problem though. Microsoft have catered for the fact that some people will want to run code at startup, before the startup form is displayed or maybe even created. There is a `Startup` event on your application and, not surprisingly, that's where you put code you want executed at startup.

If you're targeting .NET Framework, you can click the appropriate button in the Application Framework section of the project properties to create and/or open the ApplicationEvents.vb file. If you're target .NET Core, including .NET 5 or later, then you can just open the file from the Solution Explorer. You can add a handler for the `Startup` event and place your code in it to run before the startup form is created. You can also add other members in that file, e.g. methods or properties, and access them throughout your project via `My.Application`.

Comment: ok got it.  sorry, I am not so familiar with this applicationevents.

Comment: If I am going to create the myapplication.startup event, it is ok to comment out the myapplication.oncreatemainform which sets the me.mainform value.

Comment: @genesislubrigas, you're doing it wrong. If you're looking at the `OnCreateMainForm` method then you have opened the Application.Designer.vb file. DO NOT edit that file. Go back to the file I told you to open and add the event handler there. Select `(MyApplication Events)` in the middle drop-down on the navigation bar and then select `Startup` in the righthand drop-down, just as you would in a form.

Comment: @jmcillhinney, yes I am on the MyApplication Events - Startup event.  And I am using it already.  However, I just dont know if it will conflict with the OnCreateMainForm Me.Mainform =Global.appname.Form1     I just want to know.

Comment: Moreover, can I use this follow up question?      I would like to know which event comes first ?  The myapplication domain events like domain AssemblyResolve or the myapplication events like myapplication events Startup ?

I just noticed on my Myapplication_Startup, when I choose Form2.showdialog() as startup form and then close that form, Form1 will show after that.   That means, its not overriding the Form1 that is stated on the Start Up form or on the OnCreateMainForm.   I am not sure.  So what should be done in order to prevent the Form1 from showing which is not called by the code.

Comment: @genesislubrigas, what possible reason could you have for thinking that there would be a conflict? I told you that code in that event handler gets executed before the main form is created.

Comment: I just noticed on my Myapplication_Startup, when I choose Form2.showdialog() as startup form and then close that form, Form1 will show after that. That means, its not overriding the Form1 that is stated on the Start Up form or on the OnCreateMainForm. I am not sure. So what should be done in order to prevent the Form1 from showing which is not called by the code.    Oh wait, are you saying that I should not be coding the startup form code but instead the other codes I need to include before the startup form is called as set on the Startup Form. Is that right ?

Comment: @genesislubrigas, you're taking something simple and making it complicated. Are you calling `Form2.ShowDialog` in the `Startup` event handler? That has got NOTHING to do with the startup form. As I have now told already twice, the code in the `Startup` event handler is executed BEFORE the startup form is created. If you haven't changed the startup form in the project properties then the startup form hasn't changed. The fact that you show a dialogue beforehand doesn't change that. I've answered your question. I'm done here.

Comment: yeah, I got that now.   thanks so much for your assistance @jmcilhinney.  thanks for your patience too.

Answer (score 0):

**TO SUMMARIZE THE ANSWER**

First, many thanks to jmcilhinney for his assistance and patience.

So we have two options:
1st is the module Main() method, that is if you don't want to use the Application Framework. Here, you will uncheck the enable application framework so you will have the Sub Main() option from the dropdown of startup form.

2nd is the Application Events.  Here you will retain to select the startup form.
And in the ApplicationEvents.vb file, on the first dropdown, you will select the project name, on the second dropdown, you will need to select the (MyApplication Events) and on the third dropdown, you will need to select Startup.

After selecting it, the code syntax Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender as Object, e as StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup will appear.

There you will code all you need to do.  You don't need to specify in the code which form is your main startup form.  It has been already setup on the Startup Form on your project settings.

This is just a note for other beginners out there who are also searching for this answer.

Comment: Something else that might work is to have a New method as part of the form.  It will execute after the application event but before the Load event.  FWIW